# Redirect to a Report from an LWC with dynamic parameters not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-reports, lightningnavigation

I am trying to redirect to a Report from an LWC with dynamic parameters. I tried to do it manually as well nothing works. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
<div>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" onclick={redirectToReport}>View Report</a>
</div>
```

script:

```
redirectToReport(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        const data = event.currentTarget.dataset;
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: reportId,
                objectApiName: 'Report',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
            state : {
                fv0: data.date,
                fv2: data.iswon
            }
        });
    }

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DClbv.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Navigation documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) mentions `NavigationMixin` adds two APIs to your component's class:

1. `[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageReference, [replace])` - A component
   calls this API to navigate to another page in the application.
2. `[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](pageReference)` - A component calls
   this API to get a promise that resolves to the resulting URL. The
   component can use the URL in the href attribute of an anchor. **It can
   also use the URL to open a new window using the window.open(url)
   browser API.**

Bolded above for emphasis. Judging by your use of `_blank` for the target, it seems like you want to open the report in a new tab so it seems likely you'll want to use `NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl`.

You'll also want to double check your variables have data in this method and that you are using the right parameters within `state`. I see `fv0` and `fv2` but make sure you actually have 3 custom filters and are not passing invalid parameters.

`<a onclick={redirectToReport}>View Report</a>`

```
redirectToReport(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    const data = event.currentTarget.dataset;
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: reportId,
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        },
        state : {
            fv0: data.date,
            fv2: data.iswon
        }
    }).then(url => { window.open(url) }); //generate URL and open in new tab
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Kris Goncalves. Changing from  NavigationMixin. GenerateUrl and adding .then(url => { window.open(url) }); did the trick.

Comment: Unable to pass the date through the above code though since the report in lightning is not accepting customize dates.Any idea on how pass dates for createdDate of an opportunity report.

Comment: what does `data.date` contain? depends on the user's locale. It expects it as `01/01/2021` or `2021/01/01`